# bulk sms php function in a loop

Tags: php, sms, bulk

I have been using the code below to send sms to customers telling them their account balances after a given period. so far the code is able to send sms to one person at a time. Can i modify the code to send the message to all customers.

```
<?php

function sendsms($sms_username,$sms_password,$sender_ID,$number,$message)
{
    if(isset($sms_username) && isset($sms_password))
    {
        $username = trim($sms_username);//your sms user account
        $password = trim($sms_password);//your sms password
        $type = '0';//FOR FLASH MESSAGES SET type to 1
        $dlr = '1';//request for delivery report
        $destination = $number;;//phone number 
        $source = urlencode($sender_ID);//This is the sender or label that will be received by client/user. MAXIMUM 11 CHARACTERS
        $message = urlencode("$message");//message content to be sent to user/client

        //Form url api
        $url = "https://api.sendingthesms/bulksms/?username=" .$username."&password=".$password."&type=0&dlr=1&destination=".$destination."&source=".$source."&message=" . $message;

        $scc = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('protocol_version' => 1.1)));//enforce http 1.1
        $response = file_get_contents("$url",0,$scc);//fire/call nalo sms api

        return $response;
    }else
    {
        return "username cannot be empty";
    }
}


echo sendsms("username","mypassword","$session_username",$mainphone3, $mysms);
header("location:index.php");
            exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can do this.

Good practice (to me) would be, put all numbers in an array and pass into the function you just specified above. After than use Foreach to loop through all the numbers. I'm specifying an example code below. 
Hope you get the idea !

```
$numbers = ['1123234', '34343234', '12334234'];

function sendsms($sms_username,$sms_password,$sender_IDs,$numbers,$message)
{
    if(isset($sms_username) && isset($sms_password))
    {
        $username = trim($sms_username);//your sms user account
        $password = trim($sms_password);//your sms password
        $type = '0';//FOR FLASH MESSAGES SET type to 1
        $dlr = '1';//request for delivery report

        foreach($numbers as $number){
        $destination = $number;;//phone number 
        $source = urlencode($sender_ID);
        $message = urlencode("$message");

        //Form url api
        $url = "https://api.sendingthesms/bulksms/?username=" .$username."&password=".$password."&type=0&dlr=1&destination=".$destination."&source=".$source."&message=" . $message;

        $scc = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('protocol_version' => 1.1)));//enforce http 1.1
        $response = file_get_contents("$url",0,$scc);//fire/call nalo sms api


        }

        return $response;
    }else
    {
        return "username cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @fahim152. I modified my original question to include a connection to mysql database. I converted contacts column into string array as you suggested. I have posted my solution below should anyone need it.

```
 <?php 'include/dbconnect.php'; // This is for connection to the database
function sendsms($sms_username,$sms_password,$sender_ID,$number,$message) {
if(isset($sms_username) && isset($sms_password))
{ $username = trim($sms_username);//your sms user account
    $password = trim($sms_password);//your sms password
    $type = '0';//FOR FLASH MESSAGES SET type to 1
    $dlr = '1';//request for delivery report
    $destination = $number;//phone number 
    $source = urlencode($sender_ID);//This is the sender or label that will be received by client/user. MAXIMUM 11 CHARACTERS
    $message = urlencode("$message");//message content to be sent to user/client

    //Form url api
    $url = "https://api.mysmsserver.com/bulksms/?username=" .$username."&password=".$password."&type=0&dlr=1&destination=".$destination."&source=".$source."&message=" . $message;

    $scc = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('protocol_version' => 1.1)));//enforce http 1.1
    $response = file_get_contents("$url",0,$scc);//fire/call your bulk sms server's api

    return $response;
}else
{
    return "username cannot be empty";
}} $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT phonenumber FROM users");
$phonenumbers=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) $phonenumbers[]=$row[0];
mysqli_free_result($result);

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT accountbalance FROM users");
$accountbalances=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) $accountbalances[]=$row[0];
mysqli_free_result($result1);

foreach (array_combine($phonenumbers, $accountbalances) as $phonenumber => 
$accountbalance)
{
echo sendsms("username","mypassword","SendersName","$phonenumber", "$accountbalance");
}

?>
```